# On which site should I post this question about phrasing a Google search?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm writing an essay about a topic "adolescent and decision making". But, I've realized that I'm not properly/effectively using Google.

I'll want post a question about using Google effectively, but I don't know where I should  post (I posted to English but they said out-off topic)

question:

> Topic : parents let teens to make their own decision
>     Question: how should I divide that sentence and Google to take nearly best result

Comment: Did you try the search terms exactly as phrased above? `parents let teens make their own decisions` You get quite a few results. It's hard to tell you how to improve things without knowing more about what you want.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that there is a site where this would be on topic.

[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be the obvious choice - your question is about using Google search, so at first glance it would appear to be on topic.

However, you're asking for help on a very specific search phrase which ties the question very closely to your circumstances - which makes the question "too localised" and hence liable to be closed.

Comment: QChrisF, thanks, I'll try to make that question to be more general