# Where should I ask a question about Chandrasekhar's matrix decomposition?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

**Basically my question is about using chandrasekhar's matrix decomposition (physical and mathematical concept) in the study of electromagnetic scattering (physical concept) in polarimetric synthetic aperture radar (electrical engineering concept) devices.**

**Where should I ask this question to get the most attention and feedback from community members because `Chandrasekhar` was an astrophysicist but matrix decomposition is a mathematical concept and the context of my question is the application of matrix decomposition is polarimetric synthetic aperture radar studies.

I've been thinking about these sites: mathoverflow, mathematics, physics, astronomy, electrical engineering but I don't really know where I should ask my question?**

The title of my question is:
[image]
And the body of it is:
[image]

Comment: At least tell me why do you downvote? Maybe I'm not familiar with the rules? It is not off-topic for the site and there is the tag `site-recommendation` in this site!

Comment: Not one of the down voters, but did this really need asking?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M Yes I really don't know where to ask? I posted it in mathoverflow but I received no attention. They just view and make no reaction. Then I decided to post it in physics but they just upvote the question without any answer!!! And my main problem is stackexchange does not allow to post one question in multiple sites. If I do, people will start downvoting and commenting `do not ask one question in multiple sites` and they will answer my question in none of the sites

Comment: Determining the correct site is not a case of what's *in* your question, it's what is your question about - scope. Go to the sites you mentioned, look at the Help Center and see "what is on topic" "what can I ask about here". Then take a look at the tags, and search for tags you would likely use - are they already present, would they be suitable to be added? If still in doubt, look at the metas for similar questions to yours asking "can I ask about". I'm not saying you shouldn't have asked here, but I'm sure with a bit of investigating you could decide which best suits your question :)

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I saw [similar questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98101/on-which-site-should-i-post-this-question?rq=1) in this site so I decided to ask and choose the best site for posting my question

Comment: well @James I did that. I used the tags `hermitian`, `linear algebra`, `matrices` and etc in mathoverflow and then I used the tag `scattering` in physics because basically my question is about matrix decomposition (math concept) application in electromagnetic wave scattering (physics concept) studies but I didn't receive much attention?!!!

Comment: Please post only what **the question is going to be about**,  not the whole question. Here, it's just useless noise and hence the downvotes. Also, this looks like homework, and for that we don't have any SE site.

Comment: Not receiving much attention is quite different to "where do I post". First off, you have already decided *where* to post and have posted. Secondly, we have bounties for that reason :) You'd likely get more help if you asked  "I asked this question [link] but it received little attention. Was this the correct site to post on" and it should have been on the meta you have already asked the question on really/maybe.

Comment: OK @James I understood

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I honestly think that this belongs best in Mathematics.

The scope for Mathematics is simply:

> For people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields.

Your question relates to mathematics (the part about matrices) and related fields such as physics (the Chandrasekhar decomposition part). The question fits the scope quite perfectly. But you could also try asking them separately, asking the part about matrices in Mathematics and asking the part about Chandrasekhar decomposition in Physics instead.

---

You are saying that they view but don't upvote nor answer. Have some patience. The fact they haven't ***downvoted*** your question is a great thing since your question should be then considered on-topic. Maybe the question needs some further thinking and tinkering before answering, thus the wait-time. This is not the place for instant answers when you make questions. It's about ***quality*** answers, which then answers your question with clarity.

You could try improving your question as they may be a little hard to understand or something like that. You have two separate questions in your big one. One is about matrices the other one about the origin of the Chandrasekhar decomposition. Try making two different questions, containing one of two of your questions. Honestly, that seems to be the only reason holding you up (Hint: Try fixing the question about the Chandrasekhar decomposition).

You could also try bounites as a ***last resort option***.

Comment: And can I post the question in both mathematicse and physics?

Comment: I deleted my question in those sites about half an hour ago. Can I have access to my deleted questions and make them active again?

Comment: You can click "undelete" in your deleted questions to well... undelete your questions.

Comment: but I have closed the that pages in the browser. I mean is there any part in my profile from where I can access my deleted questions and undelete them?

Comment: Okay, go to your Questions tab and go straight to the bottom of the page (in the sites you posted the questions) and click on "deleted recent questions". Then you should find all the questions you have deleted and have access to undelete them.

Comment: @sepideh "*And can I post the question in both mathematicse and physics*" This is not advised. See here [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: @James, I did not say that nor recommend that.

Comment: @PythonMaster I know I was answering sepideh's comment, I forgot to include their name, sorry about that :)

Comment: @PythonMaster see this photo https://www.dropbox.com/s/indko29i0d29as3/Screenshot%202015-08-18%2003.37.43.png?dl=0 I cannot find my "deleted recent questions" in questions tab!

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the other options (votes, etc.). But who cares, you could just remake your question and post it. No big deal